# $E[\theta|x_1,x_2]=E[\theta|x_1]+E[\theta|x_2]$

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

> How should one get this relation, i.e.
>   $$E[\theta|x_1,x_2]=E[\theta|x_1]+E[\theta|x_2]$$
>    for $x_1$ and  $x_2$ uncorrelated, jointly Gaussian vectors and $\theta$ is zero mean?

This relation is from "Fundamentals of statistical signal processing: Estimation theory" by Kay, on page $432$.

He just states the claim without any proof and I was wondering about how one could get it.

Answer (score 1):

From equation $(11.17)$ of the book, we have

$$\hat{\theta}=E(\theta|x)=E(\theta)+C_{\theta x}C_{xx}^{-1}(x-E(x))$$

Also, since $x_1$ and $x_2$ are independent,

\begin{align}\hat{\theta}&=E(\theta|x)=E(\theta)+C_{\theta x}C_{xx}^{-1}(x-E(x))\\
&= E(\theta)+C_{\theta x_1}C_{x_1x_1}^{-1}(x_1-E(x_1))+C_{\theta x_2}C_{x_2x_2}^{-1}(x_2-E(x_2))\\
&=E(\theta)+[E(\theta|x_1)-E(\theta)]+[E(\theta|x_2)-E(\theta)]\end{align}

Since $E(\theta)=0$, the result holds.

My working also discloses what happens when $E(\theta) \neq 0$.

Comment: yes, according to the book with the proof of $(11.17)$ at the appendix, the results follows. But this doesnt give any intuition about what happens when  the assumptions tend not to hold. Also, it is as simple as to state the problem as $\int p(x|y,z)x\mathrm{d}x=\int p(x|y)x\mathrm{d}x+\int p(x|z)x\mathrm{d}x$ for $y$ and $z$ jointly Gaussian vectors with $E[x]=0$. Then, I dont think that $p(x|y,z)=p(x|y)+p(x|z)$ holds true even for the Gaussian case. I only find the result of Kay a bit dirty. Any idea for a nicer proof?